# LoadUserProfile for another user that is not logged in

Tags: winapi

How can i use LoadUserProfile for a user that is not logged in. This code is running within a service and needs to capture a user profile information, but that user may not be logged in when the service executes.

Comment: what information about this user you have ?

Comment: Read the [`LoadUserProfile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281.aspx) documentation. The 1st parameter is a handle to a user token. The user must be either logged in or impersonated in order for you to get that token. If the user is not logged in yet, you can log them in using `LogonUser()`, if you know their credentials.